# Why is "continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge" not being triggered by GitHub on a pull request?

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, pipeline, pull-request

In GitHub Enterprise, we have Project A under Organization A. When I submit a PR (pull request) to Project A, the `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge` is triggered which runs a Jenkins pipeline to build the code and perform unit tests. This allows us to prevent the PR from being merged into master if the unit tests fail.

For example, this is what I see on a PR for Project A in GitHub that includes a broken unit test:
[image]

Now I am trying to configure Project B under Organization B to behave the same way. However, it is not working. This is what I see on a PR for Project B in GitHub that includes a broken unit test:

[image]

Notice that Project B's PR did not kick off the `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge`.

## Configuration of Project A and Project B

**GitHub -> Settings -> Branches -> Branch protection rules**

Project A in GitHub has a branch protection rule for `master` with only one setting enabled:

- Require pull request reviews before merging

Interestingly, the "Require status checks to pass before merging" setting is not enabled. Out of curiosity, I enabled it (without saving it) and noticed that "continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge" showed up below it as an option.

I configured Project B to have the exact same branch protection rule for `master` with only "Require pull request reviews before merging" enabled. Out of curiosity, I enabled "Require status checks to pass before merging" (without saving it) and it doesn't even show `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge` as an option. It just says "No status checks found. Sorry, we couldn’t find any status checks in the last week for this repository."

**GitHub -> Settings -> Hooks -> Webhooks**

Project A in GitHub has a webhook configured with:

- Payload URL `https://jenkins.mycompany.com/github-webhook/`
- Content type `application/json`
- Let me select individual events: Pull requests, Pushes, Repositories are checked
- Active: checked

I created a webhook for Project B with the exact same settings. After I submitted a PR for Project B, I see a couple of items under "Recent Deliveries" for Project B's webhook with green checkmarks and "200" response codes, so I think it is configured correctly.

**CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise**

In Jenkins Enterprise, Project A's pipeline is of type "GitHub Organization" and has the following settings:

- API endpoint: kubernetes-cbs-automation (https://git.mycompany.com/api/v3)
- Credentials: [credentials specific to Project A]
- Owner: [Project A's GitHub organization]
- Behaviors: Repositories: Filter by name (with regular expression): Regular expression: [name of Project A's GitHub repo]
- Behaviors: Within repository: Discover pull requests from origin: Strategy: Merging the pull request with the current target branch revision
- Project Recognizers: Pipeline Jenkinsfile: Script Path: ci-cd/jenkins/ProjectA-pipeline.groovy
- Property strategy: All branches get the same properties
- Scan Organization Triggers: "Periodically if not otherwise run" checked: Interval: 1 day
- Orphaned Item Strategy: "Discard old items" checked
- Child Orphaned Item Strategy: Strategy: Inherited
- Child Scan Triggers: "Periodically if not otherwise run" checked: Interval: 1 day
- Automatic branch project triggering: Branch names to build automatically: .*

I created an item under Project B in Jenkins Enterprise of type "GitHub Organization" with the same settings (except any settings specific to Project A were replaced with the appropriate Project B specific settings).

## What is wrong/missing?

Given that GitHub PRs for Project B are failing to launch the `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge`, it seems like there is some configuration that I am missing. Unfortunately, our GitHub/Jenkins admins have not been able to figure out what is wrong.

**UPDATE**

We have confirmed that Project B is actually launching a build on the Jenkins agent when a PR is submitted. The problem is that GitHub is not showing the `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge` on the web page for the PR. We need that so the PR can be blocked if the build fails, and also so that we can quickly see what went wrong.

Comment: Does Scan Repository Now return any useful logs ? Can you see the branches and PRs in Jenkins dashboard of ProjectB ? Does the configuration for Project B in Jenkins use the same API endpoint for GitHub as ProjectA ? Does the user associated with the token used in Jenkins set as owner on both OrgA and OrgB ?

Comment: The "Scan Organization Log" just shows it processing each individual pull request and then "Finished: SUCCESS" - nothing really helpful. I don't see branches or PRs in the Jenkins dashboard of either ProjectA or ProjectB. Both Jenkins projects use the same API endpoint for GitHub. The user of the accounts used in Jenkins are not owners of either OrgA or OrgB in GitHub.

Comment: Okay that's strange .. if the scan was successful then they should appear in the dashboard however in the log it should show something like this


Getting remote branches...

    Checking branch branch-name-a
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
...


In my experience the accounts used in Jenkins is always appointed as an owner in order to have the right access to the repos etc. and then the access level can be scoped using the token scopes (like repo, admin:org_hook etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't looking in the right place, but I do see a Pull Requests tab in the Jenkins dashboard showing the PRs. There's a tab for Branches too but it shows zero branches (both ProjectA and ProjectB show zero branches). Also the log shows "Checking pull-requests... Getting remote pull requests... Checking pull request... ‘ci-cd/ourscript.groovy’ found... Met criteria..."

Comment: If you want to make Branches to show you need to add Behaviours Discover branches Strategy All branches. So basically the connection between github to jenkins works fine but jenkins isnt reporting build status only on ProjectB/OrgB. Can you please confirm if project B (and A perhaps) are public/private/internal ?

Comment: The Jenkins build logs for PRs in Project A and Project B both say "GitHub has been notified of this commit's build result" at the end. But the `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge` is showing up on the PR page in GitHub for Project A about 2 seconds after I submit the PR, well before the build finishes on Jenkins. The GitHub projects for ProjectA and ProjectB are both set to Private.

Comment: Can you please try adding the user account used in jenkins as owner to the org ideally or at least as collaborator to the projects and see if that would help with reporting of the status back to github?

Comment: Couple of things I would verify: how are the credentials configured? my guess is that they're configured differently and B doesn't have write access for updating status. Another guess: `master` could be `main` in B or `origin` could be named differently.

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan You can post an answer to claim your 50 points! I thought the user account for ProjectB had the same access as the user account for ProjectA - they both had Read access. But I changed the user account for ProjectB to have Write access, and finally it worked - a PR submitted for ProjectB kicked off the `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge`.

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan The reason why it also worked for ProjectA is because the user account for ProjectA was actually a member of the repo in 2 places - it was an individual collaborator with Read access, and it was also a member of a team with Write access. I did not realize it was a member of that team until today. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @pacoverflow Great news! - I am glad it finally works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting as answer the resolution we got in the comments.

*The issue was that the user who's token was used in Jenkins did not have the right level of access to post status checks on the repository.*

**Differences between the Orgs and Projects**

- OrgA/ProjectA - the user is a **Member** of the organisation (OrgA) also added in the Collaborators section of the repo with Read access, *as well as* member of a *Team* with **Write access** on the repo itself (ProjectA).
- OrgB/ProjectB - the user was a **Member** of the organisation (OrgB) and also in the Collaborators section on the repo itself (ProjectB) but with **Read access**.

This caused the issue on projectB status checks not being populated with Jenkins' information from the builds:
`continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge` missing from the status checks of GitHub repository.

**Summary:**
When setting up a connection between GitHub and Jenkins we need to provide the user holder of the token with the required access.

In this case we want to update the github status which needs [Write access level](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/repository-roles-for-an-organization#permissions-for-each-role):

[image: github permission level for status checks]

The token of the user should have scope `repo:status`

Comment: Thanks again. The users were not just members of the organizations, but also listed in the Collaborators section of the respective repos with Read access.

Comment: Welcome (: I updated the answer to specify that too.

Comment: For ProjectA the user was also in the Collaborators section of the repo with Read access.

Comment: Sure I added that too. I didn't specify the Collaborators section initially since adding a single user to any repo can only be done via that section.. but its good now that it is specified explicitly for better understanding.